# Wikipedia page parser for iPhone App project

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, wikipedia

i want parse a wikipedia page to retrieve information for my ios app, there is a parser or some tutorial that explain me how i can do it?...or to put the page in an xml format, i have look the http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki page, but i haven't understood nothing, if anyone can help me please..maybe with some example...

Comment: There is a WikiMedia API; but you're going to have understand how to consume web services in iOS first.  Rather than focusing on Wikipedia, I would begin with a good web services tutorial first.  [Here's one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

Comment: i already know how to consume web service in ios, i can't understand how i can parse a wikipedia page...

Comment: In that case, go the [MediaWiki API page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). Scroll down to the section "A simple example".  Use the provided URL to create an HTTP GET request.  The returned data will be the returned XML content for the marked up page.

Comment: ok i see, but don't seems an xml page, the are a whole of text without section...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [MediaWiki API page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), the page that [describes the Query action](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery), and above all else their [API FAQ](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aFAQ)? These links will tell you what URLs you should be using to get the data that you require.

Do you know how to download a URL with [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

To start with, try using their API to download a Wikipedia page of your choice in HTML format. There's an answer in their FAQ that tells you how to request HTML format. If you do that, you'll get something you could display in a web view and style as you'd like.

Comment: i already know i can take the html page from my app, but i won't display the web page, i want take some information of some page and save it in my app...

Comment: The HTML format I alluded to is not the same as the normal HTML page — it's just the content of the wiki page, without all the navigation and styling. That'll be by far your easiest way to do this. If you really don't want to do that, then firstly you need to look in the API docs for the way to make it return XML format — which sends you the content of the article in WikiText. To parse WikiText you're in for a long road… you could use [Kiwi](https://github.com/aboutus/kiwi) or [Wikiparser](https://gitorious.org/wikiparser/wikiparser) as a starting point, but they're complex C-based parsers…

Comment: thanks for the answer, in the MediaWiki Api page, there is the url example in xml format, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content
 but when i open it there isn't a classic xml page with the section, there is a whole of text in the middle, is that the xml format?

Comment: That's the WikiText. That's the thing I was saying will be difficult to parse :)

Comment: A step forward to the question. Lets say we parse based on some keywords and release an iOS app, are we not banking our trust upon the fact that the keywords & the structure in wikitext wont change in future? Is there any fail proof approach to tackle such situations?